# Sent bitcoin but was never recevied

Tags: lost-bitcoins, lost-transactions

After withdrawing bitcoin from a site I use I sent it straight to another site with a generated address, on my site it said it was completed but was never received on the other site. The three addresses are

1BVLvno6UX8Rn3KtAQgJcpcZca58bcjVc6

8uskrzBQKwbhWHL7LYFMAD5yCNH6vTLnj

37eHZRcG9G3q3ZE7a3x5qYmWnhFeiThnKR

Answer (score 1):

> **I sent it straight to another site**

Evidence suggests not.

---

At the time of writing, none of those addresses has any history of transactions in the public blockchain for Bitcoin (BTC). The second address `8usk...TLnj` does not appear to be a valid Bitcoin P2PKH, P2SH or Bech32 [address](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address)

Therefore the "site" you "withdrew" Bitcoin from, or your subsequent "sent it" (if a separate transaction), did not actually create a transaction (or at least, not a transaction that was both valid and had a sufficient transaction fee).

Consequently the money is still in its original location.

You can check addresses and transaction-IDs at any public "[blockchain explorer](https://www.google.com/search?q=blockchain+explorer)". I suggest trying several to be more confident of the information returned.

---

If I add a `3` to the start of your second address `8uskrzBQKwbhWHL7LYFMAD5yCNH6vTLnj` this makes a valid Bitcoin P2SH address which currently has been used in [six transactions](https://btc.com/38uskrzBQKwbhWHL7LYFMAD5yCNH6vTLnj) in recent days. None of those transactions involve the other addresses in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your transaction is stuck in between. If this is the case you may use bitcoin transaction accelerators. 
here is detailed article on it: https://coinfunda.com/bitcoin-transaction-accelerator-speedup-stuck-tx/